# Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? secury waring in ie, how can i fix though programing

Tags: security, internet-explorer

Ie showing following issue, how can i fix this though programing? Sorry for browser security fix

"Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?

This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the securty of the enture webpages."

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning that you're serving some content via HTTPS and some via HTTP. To avoid that warning, ensure that everything is being served via HTTPS.

Unfortunately without more details that's all the advice I can offer.

Comment: I have checked with httpWatch I can't find any http request, all are https, is any other solution to find check http request?

Comment: Can you double-check your httpWatch logs? If there are any http requests, they should show up there. Maybe try a few times? Edit: Also, I would suggest clearing your cache before trying to use httpWatch, in case the http content has been already cached in your browser.